# The difference between static library(.a) and shared object library(.so)

Tags: ros, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

Could anybody explain what difference between static library(.a) and shared object(.so) is in ROS library types?

How can I build them? Is there another type?

I have written a c++ class and build it as separate ROS pkg available for other ROS pkgs. Is it a static library?

Thanks for your explanations.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240347/the-difference-between-static-library(.a)-and-shared-object-library(.so)/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whilst not directly an answer of mine, this topic is too old to answer afresh!

[Stackoverflow Question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688200/difference-between-shared-objects-so-static-libraries-a-and-dlls-so)

[Stackoverflow Question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking)

These explain it all fairly well.

---

Originally posted by [NZNobody](https://answers.ros.org/users/27466/nznobody/) with karma: 156 on 2016-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3